# SASS - Change color based on container background color

Tags: angular, sass, colors, background-color

I'm trying to create a customizable tag component in angular, where a user would pass in a background color, and I would like to have the font color auto set to light / dark based on the passed in color.

My component looks like this:

```
<span class="tag" [ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': color}">{{ content }}</span>
```

and the ts file has:

```
@Input() color: string = '#ccc';
```

I found some tutorials for using a sass function like so:

```
@function set-notification-text-color($color) {
  @if (lightness($color) > 50) {
    @return #000000; // Lighter backgorund, return dark color
  } @else {
    @return #ffffff; // Darker background, return light color
  }
}

.tag {
  background: $notification-confirm;
  color: set-notification-text-color($notification-confirm);
}
```

but they all seem to have the **background** property defined in the file itself, which I don't have. Is there a way to figure out the current background color the 'tag' class is applied to and use that instead? Or another generic way?

Comment: what if you wrapped {{content}} in another <span> and set the inner span's color property to 'inherit'  ?

Answer (score 0):

you need use javascript to know if a color is dark or ligth. There're differents forms. If `rgb[0]` is the red (0-255), `rgb[1]` is the green (0-255) and `rgb[2]` is the blue (0-255) you has

```
isLight() {
        const hsp = Math.sqrt(
            0.299 * (this.rgb[0] * this.rgb[0]) +
            0.587 * (this.rgb[1] * this.rgb[1]) +
            0.114 * (this.rgb[2] * this.rgb[2])
        );
        return hsp < 127.5;
}
```

or

```
isLight() {
    const luminance =
        (0.2126 * this.rgb[0] / 255) +
        (0.7152 * this.rgb[1] / 255) +
        (0.0722 * this.rgb[2] / 255);
    return luminance>.5
}
```

There're some librarys to mannage colors. If you want you can check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztjvu9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcolors.functions.ts) or look for another one